# В чём ошибка этого кода? Token у меня был написан

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

```
import telebot

bot = telebot.TeleBot("TOKEN")

@bot.message_handler(contet_types=['text'])
def send_echo(message):
    bot.reply_to(message, message.text)
 
 bot.polling( none_stop = True )
```

Comment: у вас вон там скобки нехватает

Answer (score 1):

У вас тут ошибка синтаксиса в виде отсутствия закрывающей скобки в третье строке.

Answer (score 0):

Возможно дело в незакрытой скобке или разные отступы (пробелы или tab), должно быть что-то одно.